# Creating a float[] from a javax.vecmath.Matrix4f

Tags: java, opengl

What order should I populate a `float[]` using contents of `mMVPMatrix` before passing into `glUniformMatrix4fv`?

I'm using the `javax.vecmath` library.

initialize variables

```
Matrix4f mMVPMatrix = new Matrix4f();
Matrix4f mProjectionMatrix;
Matrix4f mViewMatrix;
```

set values in `GLEventListener.init()`

```
mProjectionMatrix = createPerspectiveProjection(60.0f, width / height, 0.1f, 100.0f); // method that returns an object of type `Matrix4f`
mViewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
mViewMatrix.setIdentity();
```

update in `GLEventListener.display()`

```
mMVPMatrix = mProjectionMatrix;
mMVPMatrix.mul(mViewMatrix);
```

get reference to glsl variable during draw

```
mMVPMatrixHandle = gl2.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
gl2.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
```

`uMVPMatrix` is a `glsl` variable ..

```
#version 120

uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 vPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, OpenGL assumes that matrices are stored in column major order. Based on the [Matrix4f documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/Matrix4f.html), the numbering of the matrix elements is row major. For example:

> m01: The second element of the first row.

So if `m` is a `Matrix4f`, you can build a float array `v` with elements in column major order with:

```
float[] v = {m.m00, m.m10, m.m20, m.m30,
             m.m01, m.m11, m.m21, m.m31,
             m.m02, m.m12, m.m22, m.m32,
             m.m03, m.m13, m.m23, m.m33};
```

The 3rd argument of `glUniformMatrix4fv()` also lets you choose if the matrix should be transposed while loading it into the uniform. If your values are column-major, you will use `false`. But if for some reason you have your values in row-major order, you can also use `true` as the argument, instead of shuffling the values around.